# React exluding files from being cached

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker

I am developing a project in React and I want to exclude some specific pdf files from being saved in the cache. I am using typical code for service worker provided in `create-react-app`

```
export default function register() {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {

      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

      if (isLocalhost) {
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl);

        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          console.log(
            'This web app is being served cache-first by a service ' +
              'worker'
          );
        });

      } else {
        registerValidSW(swUrl);
      }
    });
  }
```

I have no idea where should I do it and how.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. Unfortunately, it requires to use `eject` on the project. After that, we need to find a file called `webpack.config.prod.js` in the `config` folder. Then search for `SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin`. It has a parameter called `staticFileGlobsIgnorePatterns`. There we can add whatever we want. Default value is `[/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/]`.